# Issue with ora2pg exclude directive

Tags: oracle, postgresql, ora2pg

I'm using ora2pg for the first time. Migrating from Oracle to Postgres. Would appreciate if someone can help.

1. I am able to exclude tables from being exported. I include EXCLUDE in the config file. Is it possible to exclude packages and user types too?
2. Will the command below reflect excludes? I know there are 80 tables in the database being exported, and when I see the report output, I see 80 under the heading "Number" against table … which suggests to me that they are not being excluded from the calc in the report.
   CMD:   ora2pg -t SHOW_REPORT -c ora2pg.conf

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely clear for me to understand your question. But you can try this official documentation.
https://ora2pg.darold.net/documentation.html